# Incremental Rollout of Marketplace App

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are in the process of upgrading our old-marketplace app to OAuth 2 and the new marketplace. My current method of testing is to use the "Test Install Flow" button that appears in the cloud console, which will walks through the test flow and grants the requested auth to that domain. Are there any means of testing prior to a full rollout, possibly including the following?

- testing on a domain other than the domain that owns the application
- testing with a "test" marketplace listing that is not public and has not been approved
- rolling out a marketplace listing incrementally to a select list of domains

Are the google chrome store test features (publishing to only test users, etc.) available to apps for the new marketplace, in the sense that if test users can install the app for their domain?

Comment: I would like an answer to the first bullet, in particular.  Our app is inside our company domain, but we have different domain we use for testing (in the old Google Apps Marketplace we could test install on any of our domains).

Answer (score 0):

I think this similar more recent posting contains the answer (adding it here in case others, like myself find this first): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23617389/19506