# Google Apps Marketplace v2 - How to test the project created in GAMv2 with another test domain using Test Install?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have done the following steps in Google Developer Console for creating an App in GAMv2.

1. Created a project in the Google Developer Console
2. Created a web application in the project
3. Created a Service Account in the project
4. Added Google Marketplace SDK and tried with Test Install Flow.

If I need to test the install flow with the another domain before listing in the Google Marketplace, how do I test with a domain other than the Domain with which the Project is created?

If I need to create in the Chrome Webstore as a private listing, how do I test with another test domain ?

Can anyone help with this or some help links, if any, that could describe this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/project) go to your project then go to Permissions, any Member that is added there (editor or reader) will be able to go to your project and run 'Test Install Flow'.

For the chrome webstore, go to your developer dashboard (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and add a user as a tester in 'Edit your tester accounts' near the bottom. Then in your listing, set your Visibility options to 'Private' and 'Only trusted testers from your developer dashboard'.

**Edit** Note that in both cases, the user doesn't have to be in your domain.

LT